# extract R code from template using knit_expand()

Tags: r, knitr, dynamic-reports, reproducible-research

I have produced a dynamic document using `knitr`. The document makes
extensive use of the package's `knit_expand()` function for
templates. This is illustrated by the MWE (based on Yihui Xie's own
[example](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/075-knit-expand.Rnw) for the function).

- Main document `knit-expand-MWE.Rnw`

  ```
  \documentclass{article}

  \title{How to extract code when using\\
  knit\_expand() for templates?}%
  \author{Knitr User}

  \begin{document}

  \maketitle
  \tableofcontents

  \newpage
  \section{Write one row of data}

  Only the first two sections are evaluated.

  <<run-all, include=FALSE>>=
  library(knitr)
  src = NULL
  for (i in 1:3) src = c(src, knit_expand('template.Rnw'))
  @

  \Sexpr{paste(knit(text = src), collapse = '\n')}

  \end{document}
  ```
- Template `template.Rnw` called by main document

  ```
  \subsection{Now i is {{i}}}

  This chunk is {{if (i > 2) 'not '}}evaluated.
  <<row-{{i}}, eval={{i <= 2}}>>=
  # row number {{i}}
  iris[{{i}}, ]
  @
  ```

I now need to extract the corresponding R code. Running `purl("knit-expand-MWE.Rnw")` outputs `knit-expand-MWE.R`, which includes the code in the chunk with a reference to the template:

```
## ----run-all, include=FALSE----------------------------------------------
library(knitr)
src = NULL
for (i in 1:3) src = c(src, knit_expand('template.Rnw'))
```

What I would like instead is the corresponding "expanded" code (for the benefit of colleagues who do not use `knitr`), for example:

```
## ----row-1, eval=TRUE----------------------------------------------
## row number 1
iris[1, ]

## ----row-2, eval=TRUE----------------------------------------------
## row number 2
iris[2, ]

## ----row-3, eval=FALSE----------------------------------------------
## row number 3
iris[3, ]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `purl()` on `src`, e. g.

```
purl(text = src, output = 'knit-expand.R')
```

Comment: In the MWE, putting that line of code at the bottom of the `run-all` chunk does the trick. But if the chunk is instead in a child document called by the main document, then the compilation chokes with this error: `## Error in parse block(g[-1], g[1], params.src): duplicate label ’row-1’`. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if the error makes sense in this case, but you can suppress it by setting `options(knitr.duplicate.label = 'allow')`.

Comment: I **believe** the issue is that both `knit_child()` and `purl()` effectively call `knit()` on `src`, which leads to the duplicate labels (there are no duplicate labels otherwise). So the option you suggest above resolves the issue. Thanks Yihui!

Comment: You are right that `purl()` essentially calls `knit()`, which caused the issue of duplicated labels.